# SPSS - Python spss.Submit OUTPUT EXPORT loop workaround

Tags: loops, python-3.x, export, output, spss

Trying to loop with three variables to export tables to HTML. But spss.Submit() doesn't work with OUTPUT EXPORT. Possible work arounds are Looping SPSS ( I don't know how) to Export the files. Please help.

Code below:

```
BEGIN PROGRAM PYTHON.
import spss
category_to_product = {9006: [601, 602, 603]}
for categoryid,productnumbers in category_to_product.iteritems():
    for productid in productnumbers:
  path="'C:\Users\ZZZZZZ\Desktop\WWWW\XXXX\YYYY\%sSingle.htm'" %(productid)
  spss.Submit("""
USE ALL.
COMPUTE filter_$=(CATEGORYLOOP =  %s).
VARIABLE LABELS filter_$ 'Household Product Benchmarks'.
VALUE LABELS filter_$ 0 'Not Selected' 1 'Selected'.
FORMATS filter_$ (f1.0).
FILTER BY filter_$.
EXECUTE.


********************************************************************************Single Table.
OUTPUT CLOSE ALL.
CTABLES
  /VLABELS VARIABLES=Q11BI Q10 Advocacy Q11C_1 Q11C_2 Q11C_3 Q11C_4 Q11C_5 Q11C_6 Q11C_7 Q11C_8 Q11C_9 Q11C_10 Q11C_11 Q11C_12 Q10B_2 Q10B_3 Q10B_4 Q10B_5 Q10B_6 Q10B_7 Q10B_8 Q10B_9 PRODUCTLOOP 
    DISPLAY=LABEL
  /TABLE Q11BI [C][COLPCT.COUNT PCT40.0]  + Q10 [C][COLPCT.COUNT PCT40.0] + Advocacy [COLPCT.COUNT PCT40.0] +  Q11C_1 [C][COLPCT.COUNT PCT40.0] + Q11C_2 [C][COLPCT.COUNT PCT40.0] + Q11C_3 [C][COLPCT.COUNT PCT40.0]
+ Q11C_4 [C][COLPCT.COUNT PCT40.0] + Q11C_5 [C][COLPCT.COUNT PCT40.0] + Q11C_6 [C][COLPCT.COUNT PCT40.0] + Q11C_7 [C][COLPCT.COUNT PCT40.0]
+ Q11C_8 [C][COLPCT.COUNT PCT40.0] + Q11C_9 [C][COLPCT.COUNT PCT40.0] + Q11C_10 [C][COLPCT.COUNT PCT40.0] + Q11C_11 [C][COLPCT.COUNT PCT40.0]
+ Q11C_12 [C][COLPCT.COUNT PCT40.0] 
+ Q10B_2 [C][COLPCT.COUNT PCT40.0]
+ Q10B_3 [C][COLPCT.COUNT PCT40.0]
+ Q10B_4 [C][COLPCT.COUNT PCT40.0]
+ Q10B_5 [C][COLPCT.COUNT PCT40.0]
+ Q10B_6 [C][COLPCT.COUNT PCT40.0]
+ Q10B_7 [C][COLPCT.COUNT PCT40.0]
+ Q10B_8 [C][COLPCT.COUNT PCT40.0]
+ Q10B_9 [C][COLPCT.COUNT PCT40.0]
BY 
    PRODUCTLOOP [C]
  /SLABELS POSITION=ROW
  /CATEGORIES VARIABLES=Q11BI ORDER=A KEY=VALUE EMPTY=INCLUDE TOTAL = YES POSITION=BEFORE
  /CATEGORIES VARIABLES=PRODUCTLOOP[%s, OTHERNM] EMPTY=EXCLUDE
  /CATEGORIES VARIABLES=Q10 Advocacy Q11C_1 Q11C_2 Q11C_3 Q11C_4 Q11C_5 Q11C_6 Q11C_7 Q11C_8 Q11C_9 Q11C_10 Q11C_11 Q11C_12 Q10B_2 Q10B_3 Q10B_4 Q10B_5 Q10B_6 Q10B_7 Q10B_8 Q10B_9 ORDER=D KEY=VALUE EMPTY=INCLUDE TOTAL = YES POSITION=BEFORE.

OUTPUT EXPORT
 /CONTENTS EXPORT =ALL LAYERS=PRINTSETTING MODELVIEWS =PRINTSETTING
 /HTML DOCUMENTFILE =%s
 NOTESCAPTIONS =YES IMAGEFORMAT =JPG
 /JPG PERCENTSIZE=100 GRAYSCALE=NO.

""" %(categoryid, productid, path))
END PROGRAM.
```

Answer (score 0):

OUTPUT EXPORT does work in Submit.  trying printing your submitted syntax to see what is actually being run,

Note also that certain sequences of the form \letter have special meaning as escape sequences.  \t, for example, would be converted to a tab character.  Use r before your literal to prevent the escape sequence interpretation, use forward slashes, or double the backslash.